# Angular and socket that can update various scopes

Tags: angularjs, sockets

I have a multi-faceted application that allows users to communicate in realtime via socket.io. So far so good. I've written a very simple factory for socket.io and that works good too.

What I need to have the "Eureka" moment with is how to how to have my socket listen on every controller and update various parts of the app.

For example, my function:

```
socket.on('message', function(data) {});
```

Is currently in the ChatCtrl scope. Therefore if the user is say in "SettingsCtrl" the socket doesn't receive messages.

Also, I want to achieve things like on the contact list marking the number of unread messages.

So what I really need to do is have a socket that listens "globally" and then updates the scopes of various controllers.

Just a pointer of what I should be researching would be brilliant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you need your socket to listen everywhere, this is a perfect use case for [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24rootScope). All non-isolated scopes inherit properties from $rootScope. I've put together this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vHETgW6D1ItQVhh7p2iP?p=preview) that I hope helps demonstrate using $rootScope to persist your socket across various views and controllers.

If you look in app.js, you'll see the main portion that makes the socket global. After the config function, there is a run function that injects $rootScope and socket:

```
// add the global socket handler
app.run(['socket', '$rootScope', function(socket, $rootScope) {

  // add an object to rootscope that will expose variables and functions
  $rootScope.io = {
    chat: '',
    say: '',
    emit: function() {
      socket.emit('new message', this.say);
      this.chat += 'me: ' + this.say + '\n';
      this.say = '';
    }
  };

  // add additional socket functions to listen for replies, etc.
  socket.on('reply', function(data) {
    $rootScope.io.chat += data + '\n';
  })

  socket.on('clear', function() {
    $rootScope.io.chat = '';
  });

}]);
```

Now this io object is available to all scopes.  In the plunker, you can switch between various views. Even though a new controller and html partial is getting initialized, the socket and all the data that goes with it persists.

However, this doesn't mean you have to make all of the logic globally accessible. For example, view2's controller can still inject socket, listen to, and emit events for just for that particular controller. view2 keeps track of unread messages, and allows additional commands like clearing the chat or sending a ping

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It works perfectly for me. Also thank you for the plunker example. I have used the above for all my listeners and then for instance to send a message an emit that is explicitly defined in my chat controller, so your final paragraph was also important. I also now understand the relationship between $rootScope and $scope better. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)...

```
app.factory('mysocket', function() {
    var mydata; //closure
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        mydata = data;
    });
    return {
        data: function() {
            return mydata;
        }
    };
});
```

...which you can inject into various controllers.

```
function MyCtrl ($scope, mysocket) {
    $scope.data = mysocket.data();
}
```